# R/RStudio, Yosemite, and Java

Tags: java, r, rstudio, osx-yosemite

I upgraded to OSX Yosemite yesterday. When I run `library(xlsx)` in `RStudio`, the program crashes and I get the message: "To open 'RStudio' you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime." I get the same result and message about opening `R` when I run `library(xlsx)` in `R`.

Here are my details:

```
Mac Yosemite, Version 10.10.2
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) 
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
```

I have Java Version 8 update 31. I ran `java -version` and got this message: "No Java runtime present, requesting install." So I installed [Java SE Development Kit 8u31](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). Now:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

This did not do the trick because running `library(xlsx)` still crashes the program and throws a warning. Do I need to somehow roll back to Java SE 6 runtime, or is there a way to use the latest version I have installed?

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618105/rnetlogo-not-working-on-mac-yosemite/27556972#27556972) seems to be related, but I am not clear about the propsoed solution to install Java 6. The answer links to an [apple support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) that seems out of date.

I'm not familiar with Java, so I could use some advice.

Comment: you can also (from Terminal.app) `open -a RStudio` (provided your env vars are all setup well) and it will (shld) also work fine with newer JVMs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

instead the java you have installed download this one

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

after installing it, your problem will be solved

Comment: @Eric Green welcome!    Eric, if I were you, I would not upgrade to Yosemite, OMG, so many issues coming with it. Welcome to challenge :-D

Comment: I thought I waited long enough for the issues to be sorted out. Sad!

Comment: @Eric Green I personally downgraded to mavericks! if once you decided to do so, don't hesitate to comment, I will explain you how to do it :-)

Comment: @Nemo I'm facing the same issue. Does this mean the problem is coming from OS X? I would have though more from R or RStudio... I don't really want to install such an old Java version

Comment: @LudoMC This is evidently a Java 1.8 bug. See https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/37 and https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7131356.

Comment: yeah, and this screws up all the other applications that actually *need* Java 8, such as Bamboo... So, by "solving" one problem, you created a host of other ones. With Java, most problems cannot be kept in a neat sandbox. And a personal vendetta against a certain version of an operating system should be kept out of the comments. @leekaiinthesky's comment is much more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me: setting two env variables in ~/.profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/server
```

I can install the rJava and xlsx packages in Rstudio as such. Admittedly, though, it took hours of tinkering around (mindlessly) to get it just right.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get rJava loaded with Java 8.  It looks like this is a problem with RStudio not passing certain environment variables into its rsession from Yosemite.  Hopefully they'll fix it soon, but in the mean time you can pass the environment variable yourself in a terminal.  Run this:

> $LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server: open -a RStudio

Basically what you're doing here is running the java_home executable, which returns your Java path, and then appending the jre/lib/server directory.  This gets assigned to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which is what RStudio needs to correctly.