# RJDBC connection to Amazon RedShift produces a .jfindClass class not found error

Tags: r, macos, jdbc, amazon-redshift, rjdbc

Good morning,

I have successfully set up an **RStudio** environment to connect to my Amazon RedShift database on Windows and Ubuntu, but have not found the same success in OS X. I downloaded the .jar file from Amazon for JDBC and placed it in the appropriate folder ("`/etc/jdbc`"), but when I try to initialize JDBC, I get the following error:

```
.jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found
```

Does anyone have experience with RJDBC in OS X that could help me out please?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojWsd.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxCer.png

Comment: Solved by following these 2 links:  
https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/47  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by following these 2 links:
github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/47
[rJava load error in RStudio/R after "upgrading" to OSX Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite)