# installing R package openNLP in R

Tags: java, r, opennlp

I am trying to install openNLP package in R (mac) and keep getting the following error message

```
> install.packages("openNLP")
trying URL 'https://rweb.crmda.ku.edu/cran/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2/openNLP_0.2-6.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 32952 bytes (32 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 32 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/20/gzm2zpr94pz9dghqd8l5ff1c0000gn/T//Rtmp8n5kNw/downloaded_packages
> library(openNLP)
JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'openNLPdata', details:
  call: .jinit()
  error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘openNLP’


Here is my R version

> R.Version()

$platform
[1] "x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "darwin13.4.0"

$system
[1] "x86_64, darwin13.4.0"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "2.4"

$year
[1] "2016"

$month
[1] "03"

$day
[1] "10"

$`svn rev`
[1] "70301"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)"

$nickname
[1] "Very Secure Dishes"
```

I have Java installed

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

`rJava` is also installed. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: are you using Rstudio or R?, I tried it on R studio, and R it worked. try installing it again

Comment: I am using R from Mac terminal. Tried from RStudio as well but the same error

Comment: Try updating your Java; current is `1.8.0_66`. I think Apple quit pushing updates, so you've got to grab it from Oracle now.

Comment: I'm running a similar system to you. R 3.2.4, OSX (10.11.4), latest java (1.8.0_92); and your problem is replicating perfectly for me. Same error message. I used a different cran mirror (csiro.au), and also tried in RStudio (0.99.896); still the same issue. I'm thinking there might be an issue in the package itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Proposed Solution:

#### 1. Launch R at the command line (To test solution)

```
> sudo R CMD javareconf
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server: open -a RStudio
```

now within RStduio:

```
> install.packages("rJava", type = "source")
> install.packages("openNLP")
> require(rJava)
> require(openNLP)
```

#### To launch RStudio from finder... (El Capitan)

You have to link `libjvm.dylib` to `/usr/lib`...

```
sudo ln -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

now launch via finder...

## Detailed Explanation:

[rJava load error in RStudio/R after "upgrading" to OSX Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite)

Comment: I tried your method but still keep getting the same error msg.

Comment: @AshinMukherjee I updated the answer and added 1) > sudo R CMD javareconf 2) > export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Hopefully that will work for you. I was able to reproduce your problem, on my mchaine it is now working.

Comment: @Technophobe01 That works for me now. I ran the linking step before opening R, and I also did the install in R via the terminal (as per Ashin's comment under the OP). Nice work!

Comment: Thanks so much @Technophobe01 I finally got it to work :)

Comment: @AshinMukherjee Great, glad things worked out. Take care :-)