# Using RWeka M5P in RStudio yields java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: no/uib/cipr/matrix/Matrix

Tags: java, matrix, rstudio, rjava, rweka

I have an R Script which used to work fine where I use RWeka's M5P-algorithm.

For reasons unknown to me, it stopped working properly and now I get

```
Error in .jcall(o, "Ljava/lang/Class;", "getClass") : 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: no/uib/cipr/matrix/Matrix
```

Presumably this has something to do with me updating RStudio or Windows or R or some package. The odd thing is, that the script works fine when I run it from the simple R gui. So this seems to be related to RStudio and rJava (a possible problem source pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite)). Still, I don't know how to fix this, all advice I read so far concerns MacOS or Linux, but I am on Windows 10. My Java version is

```
java version "1.8.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)
```

My colleague can run the same script without problems on Windows 10 (same updates due to company policy) and RStudio (same version:  1.0.136). Her Java version is

```
java version "1.8.0_101",
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build   1.8.0_101-b13),
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

So it seems to be some accidental misconfiguration on my PC but I just don't know where to look.

Can anyone help me?

> platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32           arch           x86_64
>   os             mingw32                      system         x86_64,
>   mingw32              status                                      major
>   3                            minor          3.2
>   year           2016                         month          10
>   day            31                           svn rev        71607
>   language       R                            version.string R version
>   3.3.2 (2016-10-31) nickname       Sincere Pumpkin Patch

Comment: I would start with the path that is being used

Comment: The path is the same concerning Java

Comment: Run her machine in verbose mode, yours too; capture the messages to files, and compare. If that is equal, then you could consider jar contents

Comment: if this works let me know, I will post it as an answer

Comment: How can I run verbose mode?

Comment: the jvm has a -verbose switch. If you can't use the command line, maybe in the registry you can enable this switch. Compare the class loading section

Comment: Where would I see the output then? I need to run the script from RStudio to get the error. Would the verbose comments then appear in the RStudio log? Or where?

Comment: I would assume that it should be dumped there but I have not used that tool. Check the docs for rstudio. It may let you dump the logs to an specific file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading [RWeka Odds and Ends](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWeka/vignettes/RWeka.pdf) I realized, that my `WEKA_HOME` was set to a path in my profile and that the Weka package manager (WPM) seemed to have problems with saving the necessary modules. The solution was to set the path to my hard drive and refresh the cache.

```
Sys.getenv("WEKA_HOME") # where does it point to? Maybe some obscure path? 
# if yes, correct the variable:
Sys.setenv(WEKA_HOME="C:\\MY\\PATH\\WEKA_WPM")
library(RWeka)
WPM("list-packages", "installed")
```

Afterwards, everything got back to normal and `M5P` worked like before.