# Rstudio Knit button fail to load rJava

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, rjava

The knit button of Rstudio is failing to knit rmarkdown (Rmd) files which includes the rJava package. However, if I use `rmarkdown::render()`, the same Rmd files render into html without problems.

I can reproduce the error with the following code:

content of test.Rmd:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(rJava)
```
````

Clicking the Knit button button would return:

```
processing file: test.Rmd

Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
Quitting from lines 7-8 (test.Rmd) 
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rJava'
Execution halted
```

And `rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")` works fine. Also, running `library(rJava)` normally (not knitting) works fine too (within RStudio).

Using RStudio version 1.0.136, knitr 1.15.1, rmarkdown 1.3, rJava 0.9-8, R 3.3.2 in macOS Sierra 10.12.

**Update:** Adding output of `Sys.getenv()` as requested by @r2evans. There is a difference in the value of DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH, but I don't know if this is significant. I replace some private info with XXX.

In the html file resulting from Knit button:

```
## __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
##                       0x1F5:0x0:0x52
## Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render
##                       /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.HvKScioyGU/Render
## DISPLAY               :0
## DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
##                       /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib
## EDITOR                vi
## GIT_ASKPASS           rpostback-askpass
## HOME                  XXX
## LANG                  en_CA.UTF-8
## LC_CTYPE              en_CA.UTF-8
## LN_S                  ln -s
## LOGNAME               XXX
## MAKE                  make
## NOT_CRAN              true
## PAGER                 /usr/bin/less
## PATH                  /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
## PWD                   XXX
## R_ARCH                
## R_BROWSER             /usr/bin/open
## R_BZIPCMD             /usr/bin/bzip2
## R_DOC_DIR             /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/doc
## R_GZIPCMD             /usr/bin/gzip
## R_HOME                /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
## R_INCLUDE_DIR         /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include
## R_LIBS                /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library
## R_LIBS_SITE           
## R_LIBS_USER           ~/Library/R/3.3/library
## R_PAPERSIZE           a4
## R_PAPERSIZE_USER      a4
## R_PDFVIEWER           /usr/bin/open
## R_PLATFORM            x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
## R_PRINTCMD            lpr
## R_QPDF                /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/qpdf
## R_RD4PDF              times,inconsolata,hyper
## R_SESSION_TMPDIR      /var/folders/15/vdvn4fvx0zn0gc93_5krp6h00000gn/T//RtmpiYlwpU
## R_SHARE_DIR           /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share
## R_SYSTEM_ABI          osx,gcc,gxx,gfortran,?
## R_TEXI2DVICMD         /usr/local/bin/texi2dvi
## R_UNZIPCMD            /usr/bin/unzip
## R_ZIPCMD              /usr/bin/zip
## RMARKDOWN_MATHJAX_PATH
##                       /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/resources/mathjax-26
## RMARKDOWN_PREVIEW_DIR
##                       /var/folders/15/vdvn4fvx0zn0gc93_5krp6h00000gn/T//RtmpLe3D9z
## RS_RPOSTBACK_PATH     /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/rpostback
## RS_SHARED_SECRET      XXX
## RSTUDIO               1
## RSTUDIO_PANDOC        /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc
## RSTUDIO_SESSION_PORT
##                       XXX
## RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY
##                       XXX
## RSTUDIO_WINUTILS      bin/winutils
## SED                   /usr/bin/sed
## SHELL                 /bin/bash
## SHLVL                 0
## SSH_AUTH_SOCK         XXX
## TAR                   /usr/bin/tar
## TMPDIR                /var/folders/15/vdvn4fvx0zn0gc93_5krp6h00000gn/T/
## USER                  XXX
## XPC_FLAGS             0x0
## XPC_SERVICE_NAME      0
```

In the file resulting from `rmarkdown::render()`:

```
## __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
##                       0x1F5:0x0:0x52
## Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render
##                       /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.HvKScioyGU/Render
## DISPLAY               :0
## DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
##                       /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib:/Users/Jayme/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib::::::::
## EDITOR                vi
## GIT_ASKPASS           rpostback-askpass
## HOME                  XXX
## LANG                  en_CA.UTF-8
## LC_CTYPE              en_CA.UTF-8
## LN_S                  ln -s
## LOGNAME               XXX
## MAKE                  make
## PAGER                 /usr/bin/less
## PATH                  /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
## R_BROWSER             /usr/bin/open
## R_BZIPCMD             /usr/bin/bzip2
## R_DOC_DIR             /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/doc
## R_GZIPCMD             /usr/bin/gzip
## R_HOME                /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
## R_INCLUDE_DIR         /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include
## R_LIBS_SITE           
## R_LIBS_USER           ~/Library/R/3.3/library
## R_PAPERSIZE           a4
## R_PDFVIEWER           /usr/bin/open
## R_PLATFORM            x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
## R_PRINTCMD            lpr
## R_QPDF                /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/qpdf
## R_RD4PDF              times,inconsolata,hyper
## R_SESSION_TMPDIR      /var/folders/15/vdvn4fvx0zn0gc93_5krp6h00000gn/T//RtmpLe3D9z
## R_SHARE_DIR           /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share
## R_SYSTEM_ABI          osx,gcc,gxx,gfortran,?
## R_TEXI2DVICMD         /usr/local/bin/texi2dvi
## R_UNZIPCMD            /usr/bin/unzip
## R_ZIPCMD              /usr/bin/zip
## RMARKDOWN_MATHJAX_PATH
##                       /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/resources/mathjax-26
## RS_RPOSTBACK_PATH     /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/rpostback
## RS_SHARED_SECRET      XXX
## RSTUDIO               1
## RSTUDIO_PANDOC        /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc
## RSTUDIO_SESSION_PORT
##                       XXX
## RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY
##                       XXX
## RSTUDIO_WINUTILS      bin/winutils
## SED                   /usr/bin/sed
## SHELL                 /bin/bash
## SSH_AUTH_SOCK         XXX
## TAR                   /usr/bin/tar
## TMPDIR                /var/folders/15/vdvn4fvx0zn0gc93_5krp6h00000gn/T/
## USER                  XXX
## XPC_FLAGS             0x0
## XPC_SERVICE_NAME      0
```

**Update2** Following comments from @r2evans

Including the DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH from `render()` in the `.Rmd` changes the result of `Sys.getenv()` as expected, but the behaviour of error with knit button (same error message as above) and no error in `render()` persists. The new `.Rmd` content is:

````
---
title: "test2"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
Sys.setenv(DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib:/Users/Jayme/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib::::::::")
library(rJava)
```
````

Interestingly, using `render()` in this `test2.Rmd` just above, and including `Sys.getenv()` now outputs two new variables, not present before and not present using the knit button:

```
## DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH     /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server
## LD_LIBRARY_PATH       :@JAVA_LD@
```

I don't if it makes sense or not, but I tried a new `.Rmd` (below), which still gives the same error

````
---
title: "test3"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
Sys.setenv(DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib:/Users/Jayme/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib::::::::")
Sys.setenv(DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server")
Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH= ":@JAVA_LD@")
library(rJava)
```
````

Comment: I can't reproduce your error ... works all fine on my system, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The rest of the packages are the same as on my system.

Comment: It might be informative to run `Sys.getenv()` both in `render` and `knit`ting it. Look for differences, particularly in `PATH` and any of the `LIB`-related variables.

Comment: @r2evans Updated question with the information requested.

Comment: Have you looked for the location of `libjvm.dylib`? I might start looking in the additional `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` paths (from the second listing). If you find it there, try updating the variable with the additional path (likely in the `.Rmd` file, unfortunately).

Comment: Thanks for the help @r2evans. There is no `libjvm.dylib` file in the `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` from Knit button (`/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib`), but there is in one of the paths from the `render()` (`/usr/local/lib`). Should I copy this file (it is an Alias) into `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib`? Or write something in the `.Rmd` file? Is this issue something expected with these packages, or just a misconfiguration in my machine? I tried adding `Sys.setenv(DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib")` before loading `rJava`, but the error when knitting remain

Comment: I suggest *against* copying the library into another directory: the moment you upgrade your system installation of java, you will get a plethora of other bugs due to mixed library versions. I would have thought assigning the full set of paths (not just the one) in the `.Rmd` would have been sufficient. Can you try with the full value of `DYLD_...`, and update your question with the sample Rmarkdown that is still triggering the same error?

Comment: Having `libjvm.dylib` in `/usr/local/lib` seems odd, but what about `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/lib")` instead? If you read the [source of `zzz.R.in`](https://github.com/s-u/rJava/blob/43c11ba09f6d962f1bf348e118bd11a9261dd0cb/R/zzz.R.in) from `rJava`, it has some workarounds for osx. Perhaps that will provide some insight for other things/places to search.

Comment: I now tried `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/lib")` but the error when knitting and not when rendering remains, with the same error message. In `/usr/local/lib` there is only an Alias for `libjvm.dylib`. The original is in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server`. Tried using this `Library/Java.../ for JAVA_HOME, but the error remain

Comment: Try `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre")`. If that doesn't work, try removing one dir at a time.

Comment: Once again, thanks so much for your help. I saw an issue on github (https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/976), what makes me think it is not only some very crazy thing in my machine. I tried the JAVA_HOME full and removing one dir at a time, with and without also setting DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Setting all this, the result of Sys.getenv is the same with the knit button or render(), but the error remains. I also tried using random characters in these values in Sys.setenv, and this has no impact. With render it still works, but knit button doesn't.

Comment: Perhaps related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite

Answer (score 8):

Running the following on the command line resolved this issue for me:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue as you.  No problems loading rJava in the Rstudio R console, but experiencing a failure to load during knitting an HTML file.  Like you, I also was able to load rJava on a "knit" using the render() command.  I didn't do nearly the extensive level of testing that you did, however I eventually could successfully load rJava during a "knit" by following the link provided to you in the commments by neilfws -

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite

Then I followed the suggestion by yuan (https://stackoverflow.com/users/5697305/yuan) to load the library directly in R using the command:

```
dyn.load('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0[YOURVERSIONHERE].jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib')
```

Inserting this line in the RMarkdown file did not affect normal console behavior, but allowed for a knit using the "knit" button.  Never figured out why, but the solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know which Java you're using? I don't know enough about Java to know if my experience might help, but, when I tried to reproduce your error, I was pointed to this site:

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

where I downloaded and installed the legacy Java 6 runtime for OS X 10.11 El Capitan, OS X 10.10 Yosemite, OS X 10.9 Mavericks, OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, and OS X 10.7 Lion. Does doing so resolve your error?

I'm working on a MacBook Pro with Sierra 10.12.3, RStudio 1.0.136, rJava_0.9-8.

Comment: I am using Java Version 8 Update 121 (from the test in https://www.java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp). A while ago I had some issues relating to RJava and remember this legacy Java 6 as a proposed solution, but I solved them following some answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite. I don't think it is a Java problem because the functions work fine outside of the knitting scope.

Comment: good point about it working outside of use with the RStudio knit button.