# Installing RWeka on OS Sierra

Tags: java, r, macos, package, weka

Ok so I am almost at my wit's end with this. Major trouble with Sierra/Java compatibility (as is well-documented throughout the web and the this site). After so many steps I can't recount them all, I was able to get RJava installed and running. Also able to get NLP installed and running. But I am still having issues with RWeka. Trying, I get:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RWeka', details:
  call: .jnew("weka.core.WekaPackageManager")
  error: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: weka/core/WekaPackageManager : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/RWeka’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RWeka’ had non-zero exit status
```

I know this has been asked in other forms on here, but please don't carelessly tag this as already asked. I have not seen any posts where this is the only package with an issue.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)? Did you check which Java version is used for execution? Obviously Java7 is expected, so it must be something lower.

Comment: I guess it is similar, but none of those solutions worked for me. Still same

Comment: What about removing any Java version older than 7 that is on the system?

Comment: Ya I saw someone who had luck using the legacy version that Apple still supplies. That is how I was able to get RJava and NLP going, but no dice on RWeka. I have literally done at least 30-40 various Google searches and tried it all (I think)

Comment: What does your Java Control Panel say about your current version? (Mine says 1.8 Update 121 on the Update tab.)  It appears that yours is only finding 1.7. (I seem to remember advice _not_ to remove version 1.6 because some packages still need it, but then my machine (Macpro 3,1) is now too old since Apple has declared it end-of-life, and I cannot comment on Sierra. I wish I could remember all the stuff I tried to get JRE updated and RWeka running, but I do remember it was a struggle. (I have rJava, not RJava.)

Comment: First, the package I meant is rJava, my bad on that. Control panel says 1.8.0_121-b13

Comment: Re-tracing my steps on getting Java up to 1.8 to get rJava and RWeka to load ... I think it was this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite/34922090?s=9|2.4685#34922090

Comment: I think I am giving up on this. I look through everything and I think there are some inner workings of the system that I just don't understand, and I don't want to keep asking online and being a nag. Is there any kind of service I could pay for that would fix this up for me?

Comment: Anybody that you ask will need to know version numbers of _all_ the interconnected parts.

Comment: What versions are we talking about? R,Java, what else? R version 3.3.3 java: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13), also installed jdk  8u121