# RStudio not working in Mac OS Sierra 10.12.4

Tags: java, macos, rstudio

Hi and thanks in advance,

Don't know why but I get the following error message when trying to load a csv file in my RStudio desktop version that I have installed in my MAC:

Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rJava':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found

Could you please help me? I have tried downloading the latest version of Java, but does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to reinstall the rJava package, or run `R CMD javareconf`.

Comment: Hi! thanks, where can I run that? I have tried to reinstall java but it does not work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite) . Try running `sudo ln -f -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rJava load error in RStudio/R after "upgrading" to OSX Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite)