# rJava installation error mac

Tags: r, macos, rjava

trying to load "xlsx" package but getting the same error again and again with dependency "rJava"

```
library(rJava)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

running on Mac Osx el capitan 10.11.6 64 bit
please help

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/6f228eead691e72bd0272a25319ea9ee

Comment: So... how did you install the Java runtime and what is your PATH when you do `Sys.getenv("PATH")`?

Comment: Try solution in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31039105/2913622

Comment: x/y, but [readxl](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl) and [openxlsx](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx) are better Excel i/o packages that don't require Java.