# R, loading rJava error

Tags: java, r, rjava

I'm running R (version 3.4.0) on macOS sierra (10.12.5) and I'm trying to use the xlsx library which requires the use of the rJava library.

When I try to load rJava using `library(rJava)` in the R console (no difference if in RStudio or in the terminal), I get the following error message which I'm having trouble making sense of:

```
Fehler: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad in loadNamespace() für 'rJava' fehlgeschlagen, Details:
  Aufruf: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  Fehler: kann shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so' nicht laden:
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Googling the problem I found a number of posts on somewhat similar (but each time slightly different problems), [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite) being the most promising among them.

Since the steps of the proposed require adaptation to my case and I'm kind of a novice, I wasn't able to implement them. What can I do?

Additional information:

The shell command `java -version` returns:

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

And the shell command `R CMD javareconf` returns:

```
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_131
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
Non-system Java on macOS

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include/darwin  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -    L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server -ljvm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation


JAVA_HOME      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
Done.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It works!

After installing and reinstalling different java versions and reinstalling rJava with the R command `install.packages("rJava")` I got to the point where loading the library in the R console (shell window) didn't throw an error message anymore.

After that I was able to use the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite) to get it to work in RStudio by running this shell command:

```
sudo ln -f -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

Not too complicated after all! Thank you for everyones patience.

Answer (score 1):

JAVA_HOME path is different for different version of MAC OS. In some cases there is `/jre` folder and in some cases it is not after `/Home` director manually go towards `/server` folder with CD command in terminal and using `pwd` copy the entire path use that to set the java.home then you can easily load `rJava` library. This is how I was able to fix the issue

```
options("java.home"="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib")

Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$JAVA_HOME/server')

dyn.load('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib')

library(rJava)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I tried several SO posts and this works for macOS High Sierra. Of course, I had to change the jdk-10.jdk. Thank you @vinay-karagod