# Can't load rJava on MacOS Mojave and R 3.5.2

Tags: r, macos, rjava

I have asked [a similar question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083707/rjava-doesnt-load-in-r-3-4-2-and-macos-sierra-10-12-6), but didn't get any answers that I could actually implement. I've also read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157869/r-loading-rjava-error), but couldn't implement any of them (partially because no answer actually retraces all of its steps.

### Problem

I'm getting an error when trying to load rJava on R 3.5.2 and MacOS Mojave 10.14.3:

```
> library(rJava)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

### Attempted Solutions

I first tried [this solution](https://zhiyzuo.github.io/installation-rJava/), which didn't work. Then, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48815462/2687039), I tried the following:

Entered the following on Terminal:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Then tried the following on R:

```
> options("java.home"="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home")
> 
> Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$JAVA_HOME/server')
> 
> dyn.load('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib')
> 
> library(rJava)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I've also tried:

```
> options("java.home"="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin")
> Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH='$JAVA_HOME/server')
> dyn.load('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib')
> library(rJava)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

In the past, I've downgraded succesfully to R 3.1, but I'd rather not have to do that every time I want to use rJava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the setup that works for me

1. macOS Mojave - 10.14.3
2. XQuartz - version 2.7.11 - https://www.xquartz.org

[image]

2. R - version 5.3.2

   ```
   > R --version
   R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) -- "Eggshell Igloo"
   Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
   Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

   R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
   You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
   GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
   For more information about these matters see
   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
   ```
3. Java - 11.0.1

   ```
   > java -version
   java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)
   ```
4. rJava - installed from CRAN

   ```
   > > install.packages("rJava")
   --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
   Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
   trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-         
   capitan/contrib/3.5/rJava_0.9-10.tgz'
   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 739259 bytes (721 KB)
   ==================================================
   downloaded 721 KB


   The downloaded binary packages are in
   /var/folders/...
   > library(rJava)
   >
   ```

**Update**

In your case, it looks like JDK used during installation/compilation of rJava is missing. You can tell that from the message:

```
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
Reason: image not found
```

Make sure this file exists:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
```

Probably, it's missing. You have two options here: install Java 11.0.1, reconfigure R.

You can list all the available JVM installations using `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

**Reproducing initial issue, and fixing it**

1. Let's pretend we have removed JDK 11.0.1

   ```
   > pwd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
   > tree -L 1
   .
   |-- jdk-11.0.1.jdk~
   `-- jdk-11.0.2.jdk
   > java -version
   java version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
   ```
2. Let's try to load rJava

   ```
   > R

   R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) -- "Eggshell Igloo"
   Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
   Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

   ...
   ...
   ...

   > library(rJava)
   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
    .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
     call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
     error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
     dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
     Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
     Reason: image not found
   ```
3. Let's fix it

   ```
   > sudo R CMD javareconf
   Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
   Java version     : 11.0.2
   Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
   Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
   Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
   Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar

   trying to compile and link a JNI program
   detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/darwin
   detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
   clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
   clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server -ljvm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation


   JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
   Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server
   JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/darwin
   JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
   Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
   Done.
   ```
4. It should work now

   ```
   > R

   R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) -- "Eggshell Igloo"
   Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
   Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

   ...
   ...
   ...

   > library(rJava)
   > quit()
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not exactly the same env. Take a look at the update.

Comment: You are right, of course. I was running JDK 11.0.2. sudo R CMD javareconf only works on R terminal, though. Any idea of why this doesn't work on R GUI? Anyway, I just installed JDK 11.0.1 and got it working on R GUI. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Its usually best if you start from scratch if you have tried all these solutions and nothing worked. You wouldnt want one of these "fixes" to cause you more issues because most of them require you to change environment variables.

Here is how I fixed it.

1. Install the latest JAVA JDK  https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
2. Run `sudo R CMD javareconf` in the terminal. Dont change any of the environment variables on your own.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work. I've started from scratch, as well. After everything I done I formatted my HD and reinstalled MacOS.

Comment: OK, this only works if one is using R terminal. Any idea of why this doesn't work on R GUI?