# Loading rJava on Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: r, operating-system, rjava, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to install rJava package for running the XLConnect package. 
Here are my system details;

R studio:Version 1.0.153

Mac OS High Sierra Version 10.13.1 (17B1003)

R version: 3.4.2

jdk-9.0.1

however, i get the following error:

[image]

I have already followed the following threads on this topic but they don't work for me:

[trouble installing and loading rJava on mac El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081227/trouble-installing-and-loading-rjava-on-mac-el-capitan)

[rJava does not run on macOS Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351891/rjava-does-not-run-on-macos-sierra)

[rJava load error in RStudio/R after "upgrading" to OSX Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite)

A push in the right direction will be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: Hi, did you ever manage to solve this problem? Having major issues here.

Answer (score 4):

I used the procedure at the following website:
https://github.com/MTFA/CohortEx/wiki/Run-rJava-with-RStudio-under-OSX-10.10,-10.11-(El-Capitan)-or-10.12-(Sierra)

The main steps are:

1. Install [Apple Java 6](https://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1572/en_US/javaforosx.dmg)
2. Install the [newest Java from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
3. Fix JAVA_HOME to point to the new version. Terminal command: `sudo R CMD javareconf`
4. Install rJava from source. Terminal command: `unset JAVA_HOME; R --quiet -e 'install.packages("rJava", type="source", repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")'`

Comment: Someone downvoted this answer but didn't explain why. If this answer doesn't work, a comment would be helpful.

Comment: It worked for me, after trying lots of other options that didn't, so many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My environment is

```
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) -- "Kite-Eating Tree"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

macOS High Sierra 10.13.2
```

I encountered this problem today and spent whole day trying to fix it. Luckily I found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite) at last. It works for me.

`sudo ln -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib`

Note:

If the get `ln: /usr/local/lib/libjvm.dylib: File exists`
 in terminal. Then you should delete this file and run the command above again.

Comment: This is a frequently asked question & a major pain. Every time I have to install rJava on a new MAC there is some problem or the other. Right now this is the 4th stackoverflow question I am reading and have unsuccessfully tried to make it work. Is there a good thread where we can see step by step rJava installation along with all exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on an M1 Mac:

- Download `jdk-19_macos-x64_bin.tar.gz` from [Java](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8)
- Unzip the file and move it to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` (may need to `sudo su` first)
- Set `export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19_macos-x64_bin/Contents/Home'`
- Run `R CMD javareconf`

Answer (score -1):

@Kayle Sawyer's answer works almost perfectly, but you might need to reinstall command line tools first.  Easiest way is to run the following in Terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

If you get an error saying command line tools are already installed, you can reinstall the package with this:

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/
open macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

You might need to update the second command based on your OS version.

Answers from https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/338