# Java issue with h2o - not recognizing java version

Tags: java, r, macos, h2o, rjava

I've always used a Mac and don't remember encountering this in the past so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.   Theres a bit of q's on this on the internet already but I didn't find a solution yet for me.

I just got a new mac and I'm trying to use rJava & h2o specifically.  Below is a couple of things I ran and the output from them.   Can someone help me out?

```
Java --version
```

> java --version java 10.0.1 2018-04-17 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
>   18.3 (build 10.0.1+10) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)

```
Javac --version
```

> javac 10.0.1

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

> Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
>     10.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 10.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
>       1.8.0_171, x86_64:    "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home
>
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home

```
Sys.getenv('JAVA_HOME')
```

> "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk"

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
```

> H2O is not running yet, starting it now...  Error in value[3L] :    You have a 32-bit
>   version of Java. H2O works best with 64-bit Java. Please download the
>   latest Java SE JDK 7 from the following URL:
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

I definitely have the 64 bit of java installed as I re-installed it to be sure and see above the x64 notification from the output. Also, I have gotten this to work on another computer and so I don't understand what is going on  with this one.

I also did

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
EXPORT JAVA_HOME = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk"
```

but this doesn't seem to help me target the Java 8.

Comment: I just wanted to point out / clarify that H2O does not use rJava, it sounds like you are suggesting that rJava is required by H2O.

Answer (score 3):

You have various problems.

H2O currently does not support Java 10 (that you are using). You need to use Java 8 or Java 7.

`Supported versions include: Java 7 or later. 
Note: Java 9 is released, but is not currently supported. 
Java 9 support will be added in an upcoming version.`[h2o website](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/welcome.html)

For `rJava` on Mac I send you to 
[Loading rJava on Mac OS High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658210/loading-rjava-on-mac-os-high-sierra)

I am running h2o on a mac with high sierra (and rJava, for a different project) with R v. 3.4.4 and **Java 8**. All good.

Comment: I got Rjava to work by installing the Java 8 on the website - JDK 1.8.0_171.   However, I'm not able to get h2o work.  when I use H2o I still get 
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode).    I adjusted my .bash_profile to be --> export JAVA_HOME = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk"


export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server"
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

Comment: 2 things: 1. how did you install/build h2o? (I suggest this one http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wolpert/8/index.html); 2. R: are you in the terminal or in RStudio?

Comment: actually @Pasqui , I'm having a bit of trouble.  Somehow it broke and I'm not allowing it to work anymore..  I updated the post with a description.