# Using Rjava on Mac. Relevant library libjvm.dylib does not exist

Tags: java, macos, rjava

I cannot use R with Java on the Mac. There is a wealth of information on the web, including on Stack Overflow (e.g. [rJava load error in RStudio/R after "upgrading" to OSX Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite)), but none of this helps me. The standard advice is to find the file libjvm.dylib, and to set up a link to this as follows;

```
sudo ln -f -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

The problem is that I do not have the file libjvm.dylib anywhere on my system, despite repeatedly downloading the latest version of Java from Oracle.

My Java home is as follows; /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home.

The Java version is; java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode).

The tree structure of my java home (directories only) is;

[image]

It looks completely different from the tree structure which I'm supposed to have, e.g. there is no 'jre' folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to make symbolic links etc. You simply need to properly configure Java and R to get them running smooth.

Take a look here: [R, Java, rJava and macOS adventures](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3671)

Recently, I have updated this entry for more recent R - R 3.4. Take a look here: [R 3.4, rJava, macOS and even more mess ;)](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3718)

Maybe this time it will help ;)

Comment: Thanks, I followed your advice, but I still get the following error; unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found

Comment: My problem is sorted. I reloaded Java 8, and the relevant files (libvjm.dylib and rJava.so) have appeared. I do not know what I did wrong previously. Thanks for help.

Comment: .oOo. Cool! Thanks for accepting the solution .oOo.