# rJava loading error

Tags: java, r, rstudio, rjava

Like a bunch of people, I am having trouble getting rJava to load in RStudio -- the same problem also reproduces itself when using the R GUI directly.

Here's the error:

```
> require(rJava)
Loading required package: rJava
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I have tried a number of things, including reconfiguring from the command line:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf -n

Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_144
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
Non-system Java on macOS

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/../include/darwin  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server -ljvm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation


JAVA_HOME        : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/darwin
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
```

When I check `options("java.home")` it was set to `NULL`, so I set it to the following:

```
> options("java.home"="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre")
```

I also reinstalled Java SE Development Kit 8 and then resintalled `rJava`.

Regardless, I continue to get the same error.

Here is my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.3-2 scales_0.5.0     compiler_3.4.1   lazyeval_0.2.0  
 [5] plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.4.1      gtable_0.2.0     tibble_1.3.4    
 [9] Rcpp_0.12.12     ggplot2_2.2.1    grid_3.4.1       rlang_0.1.2     
[13] munsell_0.4.3
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Quickest solution was to manually load the `dylib`.

```
dyn.load('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib')
require(rJava)
```

If the above solution works, a long term solution exists by adding this command to the terminal.

```
sudo ln -f -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

Found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite). You will no longer need to manually load the `dylib` each time.

Comment: on my system, with a more recent version of java, the path is different, so the command is `dyn.load('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib')`

Answer (score 1):

When re-installing java on a Mac OX system, you need to close all your r sessions and then to use the system command line `R CMD javareconf`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it does not fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is something that took me quite lot of time to solve in mac OS.

You can try these:

[R 3.4, rJava, macOS and even more mess ;)](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3718) and this one [R, Java, rJava and macOS adventures](http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3671)

You can find quite detailed instructions there. However, note that some people face system specific issues following these instructions :(

And it's hardly possible to find solution that solves all the issues people find.

Answer (score 0):

For me this instruction did it:

https://cimentadaj.github.io/blog/2018-05-25-installing-rjava-on-windows-10/installing-rjava-on-windows-10/

if you have installed Java before try to deinstall and reinstall it like:

Windows 10 - Uninstall Programs

1. Click Start.
2. Select Settings.
3. Select System.
4. Select Apps & features.
5. Select the program to uninstall and then click its Uninstall button.
6. Respond to the prompts to complete the uninstall.