# rJava errors loading registerDoSNOW() or any external RStudio process

Tags: r, osx-yosemite, rjava

```
> registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(4, type="SOCK")) Loading required package: methods Loading required package: DBI Loading required
> package: rJava Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’: 
> .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:   call:
> dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)   error: unable to load shared
> object
> '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so,
> 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib   Referenced from:
> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
> Reason: image not found Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
> Execution halted
```

This also happens if I try to use Knitr. So it is not related to registerDoSNOW() but to rJava and some kind of wrong pathing.

I've researched the common solutions (e.g., [rJava load error in RStudio/R after "upgrading" to OSX Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite)) to rJava not loading.

1) My Java is 64 bit version
2) `library(rJava)` loads fine
3) It's only when I try to use `registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(4, type="SOCK"))`

This only started happening after I upgraded to R 3.4.2 from 3.3. I upgraded because `data.table` complained that it could not make use of 64 bit architecture. When I upgraded, RStudio wouldn't run Java, which I fixed by executing `sudo ln -f -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib`

I tried the solutions here http://paulklemm.com/blog/2015-02-20-run-rjava-with-rstudio-under-osx-10-dot-10/ with no avail.

> java version "1.8.0_101" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_101-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this process will solve your issue.

1. install rJava from within a r terminal
2. run `ln -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib`

   - if the file already exists, overwrite it with `sudo ln -f -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib`
3. run `R CMD javareconf` in a mac terminal session

Basically you're just setting up the java file that rJava needs and then reconfiguring R so it knows where to look.

If you get an error with something like /opt/X11/lib/* in it, then you need to install XQuartz, which can be found [here](https://www.xquartz.org/).

Comment: `R CMD javareconf ` for the win! Thank you!