# Error: package or namespace load failed for 'XLConnectJars'

Tags: java, r, xlconnect

I've installed the XLConnect package and attempted to load it in my R script.
However, an error occured as below. As I have no knowledge about Java, after googled around I still find no way to solve this.

```
> library(XLConnect)
Loading required package: XLConnectJars
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'XLConnectJars':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package 'XLConnectJars' could not be loaded
```

Comment: Looks like a Java installation/configuration issue. The suggestions in the following SO question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite

Comment: If there is no specific requirement for XLConnect, try `openxlsx`. It is not dependent on java.