# Connecting Spark with R studio on Mac OS gives Hive error

Tags: r, sparklyr

I am trying to use Spark in R Studio using the `sparklyr` library on MacOS. I have installed it using the following commands

```
# Install the sparklyr package
install.packages("sparklyr")

# Now load the library
library(sparklyr)

# Install Spark to your local machine
spark_install(version = "2.1.0")

install.packages("devtools")

# Install latest version of sparklyr
devtools::install_github("rstudio/sparklyr")

# Connect to Spark
options(sparklyr.java9 = TRUE)

sc = spark_connect(master = "local")

iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris) # Throws hive error !!!
```

Here is the error that I am facing -->

> iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris)
>   Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:981)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:110)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:109)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:878)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
>       at sparklyr.Invoke$.invoke(invoke.scala:102)
>       at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:97)
>       at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.read(stream.scala:62)
>       at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:52)
>       at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
>       at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:978)
>       ... 44 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:169)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.(SharedState.scala:86)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:101)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState(SparkSession.scala:100)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.(SessionState.scala:157)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.(HiveSessionState.scala:32)
>       ... 49 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:166)
>       ... 57 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf when creating Hive client using classpath: file:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/sparklyr/java/sparklyr-2.1-2.11.jar
>   Please make sure that jars for your version of hive and hadoop are included in the paths passed to spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars.
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:270)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:366)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:270)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
>       ... 62 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
>       ... 65 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.(HiveClientImpl.scala:97)
>       ... 70 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf
>       at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1.doLoadClass(IsolatedC

Comment: What OS are you using? (i.e. is it High Sierra, El Capitan, etc)? And what version of Java do you have installed?

Comment: My OS is High Sierra and Java version is 1.8 -->  jdk 1.8.0_161

Answer (score 0):

New Mac OSX releases have a documented problem of messing up the Java path in R/RStudio (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite)). I have a feeling (though I'm not 100% certain) that this is what you're encountering here.

If you check out the question I've linked above, hopefully you can find a solution that works to reset your path; the one I found that best worked for me on High Sierra was:

```
dyn.load('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib')
```