# Conflicts between MacOS High Sierra and R packages

Tags: r, package, rjava, macos-high-sierra

I am running MacOS 10.13 (High Sierra) and recently updated to R version 3.4.3 and R studio version 1.1.419.  For some reason the rJava package is not working...tried several fixes from here on stackoverflow and nothing works.  Also, the digest package will not load so I can no longer use ggplot2.  Any suggestions?

Error for Java:

```
    > library("rJava", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Error for digest package:

```
    > library("rJava", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Please provide the error messages you are getting.

Comment: The second error message is also for `rJava`, not for `digest`.

Comment: What solutions have you already tried, and what version of Java are you running?

Comment: Sorry....I copied and pasted the wrong code for digest.  I'll change it.

Comment: Thanks for your "digest" solution, John M.  That worked.  When I get a little time I will work on the Java solution a little more...

Comment: I am running Java 9.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

New Mac OSX releases have a documented problem of messing up the Java path in R/RStudio (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite)). It looks as though that this is what you're encountering here.

If you check out the question I've linked above, hopefully you can find a solution that works to reset your path; both of the commands below worked for me.

```
dyn.load('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib')
```

or

```
sudo ln -s $(/usr/libexec/java_home)/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the problem with `rJava`, but `digest` was just updated so if you try to install the binary it may not compiled and built yet.  If that ever happens (it's somewhat of a race condition/lag), you can try to reinstall form source:

`install.packages("digest", type = "source")`