# rJava load error in RStudio

Tags: java, r, rstudio, rjava

I have just updated my R-Studio to version 3.3.3. to 3.4.3 in OSX
I am trying to open an excel file using package xlsx, and have also re-installed rjava, but on executing the library(rJava) it gives me the following error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rJava':  .onLoad failed
>   in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:   call: dyn.load(file,
>   DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)   error: unable to load shared object
>   '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
>   dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so,
>   6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
>   Reason: image not found

I have tried few fixes described here ([rJava load error in RStudio/R after "upgrading" to OSX Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite)) but it doesn't work for me. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: did you run `R CMD javareconf`?

Comment: @DavidGohel Yes, I did, but I still get the following error. (Sorry, I didn't mention that I use a Mac OS. (*** JAVA_HOME is not a valid path, ignoring
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.6.0_65
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
Non-system Java on macOS)

Comment: And were all your R sessions closed?

Comment: @DavidGohel yup they were closed. I am a newbie in using R. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the rjava as well, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: ok. (FYI, rJava can difficult to install). I don't think you need `JAVA_HOME`. I never needed it ;) What is your java version?

Comment: @DavidGohel my java version is : rJava_0.9-9

Comment: no, java version? in a terminal, run `java --version`

Comment: @DavidGohel sorry, its java version "1.6.0_65"

Comment: Could you remove JAVA_HOME and then run (all R sessions closed) R CMD javareconf and show the output? (edit your question as it's difficult to read in comments)

Comment: @DavidGohel How shall I remove JAVA_HOME? When I run -R CMD javareconf it gives the same error.

Comment: Yes, the error is telling you that JAVA_HOME is wrong: "JAVA_HOME is not a valid path". You have a env variable named JAVA_HOME that does not point to a valid path, remove it (unset)

Comment: @DavidGohel I unset the path as suggested. (wrote the following to my bash file:                                                                                                        export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6.0_65)/jre
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/server
unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.                                                                            It still doesn't work.

Comment: I mean unset all env variables you could have set and let R CMD javareconf do the work. See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Java-support

Comment: @DavidGohel I have unset the JAVA_HOME variable (I could only found this env variable) and run R CMD javareconf. Now, it does not show me that JAVE_HOME is an invalid path but gives me another error   (missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
Unable to compile a JNI program) and (Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
Done.) I tried to run rJava again in R studio, and it gives the same error as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Oh sorry, you said you wrote export instructions in your bash file... OK, so now you need to install xcode with command `xcode-select --install`

Comment: @DavidGohel Sorry for the confusion I may have created David. I have now installed the xcode. :-)

Comment: @DavidGohel Sorry for the confusion I may have created David. I have now installed the xcode. :-)

Comment: @DavidGohel now when I run R CMD javareconf, it gives me the following error:                                                                    
conftest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
#include <jni.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program

Comment: if you are still trying, reinstall java, then run R CMD javareconf (or sudo ...) and then you should be able to install rJava. If not working, I can not do more... On my mac os X, I just installed java, then ran R CMD javareconf and it worked. I think most people are messing their config by trying to add env PATH, linked, etc... :)

Comment: @DavidGohel thanks for your time David. I am still trying to fix this problem. I will post the solution here, hopefully, i'll get one :-)

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled Java again, the rJava works now :-)

Comment: cool. I will try to make a note of this later.