# ‘rJava’ could not be loaded after installing R version 3.4

Tags: r, terminal, rjava

```
Loading required package: xml2
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: methods
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':

dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
Referenced from:       /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/r    Java.so
Reason: image not found
Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
Execution halted
```

I'm getting this error a day after I installed version 3.4 of R. I tried [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite) from other pages but it didn't work. I can't run R scripts through the terminal but I run scripts on RStudio. I'm thinking that it might be a problem with paths, but I just wanted to double check here and confirm instead of getting myself into a deeper mess.