# Synchronizing R system settings from Terminal, GUI and RStudio

Tags: r

My problem on my MacOS is that I can use R from GUI (aka console, downloaded from CRAN), Terminal or from RStudio but I cannot have them function in the same way.

Specific example is I can use rJava on Terminal and RStudio but not on GUI. Similar stuff happens for Rmarkdown pdf outputs. I usually get errors from GUI but everything is fine on Terminal or RStudio. How do I update R GUI settings to the same as Terminal's?

ps. For instance `R CMD javareconf` command handled the Terminal R but not R GUI.

edit: It is not actually something that requires a minimal working example but let's try `library(rJava)` after installing it.

#### R Called from Terminal (same with RStudio)

No problems.

[image: From Terminal]

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0
```

#### R GUI

[image]

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0
```

Some differences between Sys.getenv() are GUI has the following extra

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH                :@JAVA_LD@
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH              /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server
```

Brief update: I was able to correct Rmarkdown situation by [using this link](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#I-get-_0060_0060command-not-found_0027_0027-in-the-GUI-yet-it-works-in-the-Terminal-_002d_002d-why_003f) and reading help by writing `?Startup` on R console. Changed the `Renviron` file on my `R.home()/etc/`. But still no `rJava`.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: We'll need `sessionInfo()` output from all of the environments. the output of `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile`. The output of `Sys.getenv()` from all environments too. Oh, you also should likely not post some of those bits as they may contain sensitive data (like tokens or credentials). `rJava` is notoriously difficult to get working in general.

Comment: I got half of my responses from this tiny FAQ item: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#I-get-_0060_0060command-not-found_0027_0027-in-the-GUI-yet-it-works-in-the-Terminal-_002d_002d-why_003f but rJava problem persists.

Comment: Added info to the question. No bash_profile on this Mac somehow.

Comment: I don't know if it is still relevant but rJava's rJava.so file explicitly states jdk-9 while I have 10. @hrbrmstr

Answer (score 0):

For R Markdown problem, I managed to handle it by adding a `~/.Renviron` file and defining `PATH` parameter with the value I got from Terminal's `Sys.getenv()` parameters.

The only thing that worked for rJava for High Sierra is the following answer (changed the version to 3.5 though)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47685001/3608936