# Unable to load RWeka package

Tags: r, rweka

I have tried adding the path in the terminal using the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite) and it said was successfully added but still I am unable to load the RWeka package.

It is giving me the below error -

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RWeka’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Symbol not found: _EXTPTR_PTR
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘RWeka’ was built under R version 4.0.2

What could be done? Please Help!

Comment: I suspect that there is a problem with your `Java_Home` environment variable which RJava uses to connect to Java.  In a command prompt,  type `set Java_Home`.   It will show you the current value.  Check that it is the correct path to Java.  If not,  change your environment variable. This sometimes happens after an update to Java.

Comment: I am using Mac OS Catalina 10.15.5

Comment: You still need to set Java_Home.  Try [This Web Page](http://www.sajeconsultants.com/how-to-set-java_home-on-mac-os-x/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=how-to-set-java_home-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: I tried setting Java_Home but it is not showing up in the .profile What to do now?